# Gotchas when switching from .indexOf() to .search()

Tags: javascript, regex

I’ve used `indexOf` to search for a `term` within a `text` (both are strings), like so:

```
if (text.indexOf(term) > -1) { …
```

However, I would like the search to *not* be case sensitive. I’ve tested with performing `.toLowerCase()` on both strings, but the performance penalty of doing that is significant (I’m searching on an array of `text`s with thousands of elements). I’m therefore considering switching to `.search()`, like so:

```
var re = new RegExp(term, 'i');

// and then
if (text.search(re) > -1) { …
```

Is this approach feasible? How can I make sure that the `term` is treated “literally” in this scenario, i.e. that certain characters in `term` aren’t interpreted as special characters?

Comment: I would suggest to use `test` instead of `search`

Comment: This is how you escape regex metacharacters: [Is there a RegExp.escape function in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3561493/5290909)

Comment: @Tushar I’ve tested (via `console.time/timeEnd`) and there seems to be no difference in performance. (`test` is still better for my scenario though)

Comment: @Mariano Aha, so “escaping metacharacters” means they become literals in the regex. It seems to work on this simple example: https://jsbin.com/foradi/edit?js,console

Comment: That's exactly what it means.

Comment: if it's slow, you can make such a task ~25 times faster by using 26 different arrays, a-z by first letter, then looking only in the related sub-set array to find matches... ok, if these are real words, it will probably only be 10X faster since RSTLNE will hog a lot of action... same RAM though...